# Index error when trying to find positions of array values

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, index-error

I am trying to find the position of each element in "out_max" in an array "out_der". I want to store the indexes of each value's position in an array called "out_pos". "out_der" is a 400x300x60x27 array and "out_max" is a 400x300x60 array. "out_pos" should also be a 400x300x60 array. I tried converting "out_der" to a list and using `.index()`, but that did not work (as the list only had 400 elements). This is my current attempt:

**INPUT:**

```
    out_max=[]
    out_pos=[]
    out_max=np.amax(out_der,axis=3)

    for i in range(0,len(out_der)-1):
        out_pos[i]=np.where(out_der==out_max[i])[0]
```

But I get this error:

**OUTPUT:**

```
       18 for i in range(0,len(out_der)-1):
  ---> 19     out_pos[i]=np.where(out_der==out_max[i])[0]

  IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: `out_pos` is an empty list at the start, so all indexing is out of range. You probably want `append` but I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're doing.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: Initialize `out_pos` as `out_pos=[[]] * len(out_der)`.

Comment: In other words, the error comes from `out_pos[i] =`. It's nothing to do with numpy.

Comment: @roganjosh it wont let me use `append` , I think because it's not a list

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you initialized 1D arrays where you need to initialize out_max and out_pos = np.empty((400,300,60))

Answer (score 0):

You say

> "out_pos" should also be a 400x300x60 array

but you are declaring it with

`out_pos=[]`.

Which makes it a 1 dimensional 0 length list.

To create a 400x300x60 array with all of the values initialized to 0, use

`out_pos = np.zeros((400,300,60))`.

If you want a specific value in the array that isn't zero, you can use

`out_pos.fill(value)`

after creating it.

Comment: @WalterBlair Thank you, that completely slipped my mind. However when I fix that I get this error: `     17 for i in range(0,400*300*60):
---> 18     out_pos[i]=(np.where(out_der==out_max[i]))
     19 
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (60) `